# Behave background with multiple examples

Tags: inheritance, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

I'm writing a feature for scenarios that are inherited between multiple classes. I'm new to behave so hoping I'm missing something basic...

It would be nice to have a shared setup for all of them and have the whole feature be run against the examples:

```
Feature: Car
   Background: Once a {car_type} of car has entered the assembly line
   
   Examples:
     |car_type|
     |truck   |
     |van     |

   Scenario: Can drive
     When the wheels are added to the car
     Then it can drive 

   Scenario: Can honk
     When a horn added to the car
     Then it can honk
```

Currently instead I have to define the setup for the background in every scenario so I can define multiple examples.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for your problem is to use the basic syntax:

```
Feature: Car

Scenario Outline: Can drive
  Given Once a "<car_type>" of car has entered the assembly line
  When the wheels are added to the car
  Then it can drive

  Examples:
    | car_type |
    | truck    |
    | van      |

Scenario Outline: Can honk
  Given Once a "<car_type>" of car has entered the assembly line
  When a horn added to the car
  Then it can honk

  Examples:
    | car_type |
    | truck    |
    | van      |
```

It could be possible to only define the example array in one place in your code as a Python variable and use `context.execute_steps()` (see more in https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#behave.runner.Context.execute_steps) but you will have only one massive Scenario where will be tested all the examples at once and it would be worst solution than repeating the examples in all Scenarios.